# @FetchRequest - using NSPredicate - only accepting

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to filter @FetchRequest using NSPredicate. It works as required when I pass the string directly `NSPredicate(format: "type == 'test'")` Yet when I pass in a variable Xcode complains. Thanks in advance.

Works fine
[image: Works fine]

Does not work
[image]

Comment: Hi Jack, try this if it helps NSPredicate(format: "type = %@", "\ (filter)")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a very good explanation, with example code on Paul Hudsons, public resource,  Hacking with Swift Web Site.

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/dynamically-filtering-fetchrequest-with-swiftui

Answer (score 0):

The error says that you cannot access the variable `filter` (which equals `self.filter`) in your init method.

Is this all of your code? If the `@FetchRequest` line is in your init method, move it after super.init() or move it in a method that is executed after init() is done.

Answer (score 0):

Place the fetch request inside

init(filter: String) 
{ your fetch request }

then call AddSetView(filter: yourFilter)

I have recently done something similar experimenting with SwiftUI.  In my case, the user creates a category, and when the selected category is tapped, I list the todo items specific to the category.  So I need to filter my results by selected category.  My code is as follows, hope it helps:

```
struct TodoList: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context

    var fetchRequest: FetchRequest<Todo>

    init(filter: String) {
        fetchRequest = FetchRequest<Todo>(entity: Todo.entity(), sortDescriptors:[
            NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Todo.dateCreated, ascending: true)
        ], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "parentCategory.title == %@", filter))
    }
```

I call the view as follows:

```
TodoList(filter: selectedCategory.title!)
```

the final piece of the puzzle was to add a variable to the extension in my Todo+CoreDataProperties.swift

I found the solution to the extension over at Hacking With Swift. https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/dynamically-filtering-fetchrequest-with-swiftui

```
var wrappedTodo: String {
    parentCategory?.title ?? ""
```

}

I had to set my core data entitys codegen to Manual/None and then create NSManagedObject Subclasses.  Initially this gave all sorts of errors, so I had to delete my model.  Create a new one, set the codegen for each entity to manual/none.  Then create the NSManagedObject Subclasses (Editor > Create NSManagedObject Subclass). I was then able to compile without errors. You should then be able to edit you (Entity)+CoreDataProperties.swift file.